# springboot look for wrong sequence to insert into postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I have an entity;

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
public class Organization {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
.
.
.
```

I created the table:

```sql
create table organization (
    id int generated always as identity primary key,
    name text unique not null
);
```

As a result of this query, `organization_id_seq` is created in the db.

When I send request and try to insert data, it fails with the error message

```
jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: relation "organization_seq" does not exist
```

`organization_seq` really does not exist but `organization_id_seq` exists, how can i fix this?

I have tried `GenerationType.AUTO` the result was the same error.

Comment: Why does your code even try to touch the sequence? The whole idea behind an identity column is to let the database handle the identity, not an external source like your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `GeneratedValue.strategy` to `GenerationType.IDENTITY`.

This is the correct strategy to use when the table has an identity column for the PK.

What `AUTO` does depends on the datatype of the PK and the database and in your case seems to end up trying to use a sequence.
If you want to use a sequence create a sequence with the proper name in your schema creation script and drop the identity declaration of the id column.

See for example https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers for more about how ids can get generated.